# How to get total from two tables and use the value for calculations? (sql, asp)

Tags: html, sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I want to find the total in tblCreatedItems and tblInventory within the past week of the current date. The Total for tblCreatedItems displays perfectly fine. But the one for tblInventory doesn't show at all.

My tables are:
tblItem(ItemID, ItemName, Price)
tblCreatedItems(ItemID,Quantity)
tblInventory(IngredientName,Price, Quantity)

Currently this is my code:

```
<% dim Con,rs, sql

set con = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Con.Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("Database/Name.accdb"))

sql = "SELECT  tblItem.Price, tblCreatedItems.Quantity, tblCustomer.OrderDate, Price InventoryPrice FROM tblCreatedItems,tblInventory, tblItem, tblCustomer WHERE tblCustomer.OrderDate BETWEEN Date() AND Date()-6 AND tblItem.ItemID=tblCreatedItems.ItemID AND tblCustomer.CustomerID=tblCreatedItems.CustomerID"

rs.open sql, Con
%>
<form name="InsertFinancialInformation" method="post" action="">
    <table class="Table" align="center" >
        <th colspan="4">Financial Information Entry</th>
        <tr><td colspan="4" bgcolor="#999999">Cost of Sales:</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Opening Stock</td> 
            <td>Purchases</td>
            <td>Gross Profit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <%while not rs.eof%>
            <%
                dim Total

                Total = Total + (rs("Price")*rs("Quantity"))
            %>
            <% rs.movenext
               wend
            %>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="<%response.write(Total)%>"/></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="
<%while not rs.eof%>
            <%
                dim InventoryTotal

                InventoryTotal = InventoryTotal + (rs("tblInventory.Price")*rs("tblInventory.Quantity"))
            %>
            <% rs.movenext
               wend
            %>
<%response.write(InventoryTotal)%>"/></td>
            <td><%response.write(Total-InventoryTotal)%></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to involve tblInventory at all.

Comment: Dreadful table structures, consider restructuring them. It's called a *Relational* Database Management System *(RDMS)* for a reason.

Comment: These two tables are for storage. So any information that is not required in the main system is copied into here after using. and ItemID is a FK in tblCreatedItems

Comment: Wow, there's a piece of the puzzle which would have been nice in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop is moving through the recordset until it gets to the end. Then your second loop tries to do the same. However the recordset is already at the end so there aren't any records left to loop through. You'll need to requery the db just before the second loop or use rs.movefirst (I'm not too sure if that is a valid command with classic asp though).

Comment: Yeah I tried that just now but it is looping the same thing more than it should. So it repeated for every item in the other table. Eg of table 1 has 6 records table two will loop 6 times

Comment: that would be your SQL. It looks like you are matching id's between a few of the tables but not the inventory table. Thats probably why you are exponentially looping.

Comment: Inventory is each separate ingredient, so how will I be able to match it up with a different table. This table doesn't like to another table. I am matching the ids to get the information of an item in that table from another table.

Comment: Somehow you will need to build a query that links your inventory table with  the OrderDate in your customer table. We'll need more info on your database schema before suggesting an actual query.